# pset3 plurality - candidates votes are not being updated - CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I trying to finish pset3 for CS50, plurality and my code does not update the votes for each candidate. I have implemented the vote function, but it seems not to work. Do you know where I need to improve my code?

This is my code at the moment:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++ ;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    int highest_vote = 0;
    string winner;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes >= candidates[0].votes)
        {
            highest_vote = candidates[i].votes;
            winner = candidates[i].name;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", winner);
    return;
}

INPUT:

./plurality a b c d
Number of voters: 5
Vote: a
Vote: a
Vote: b
Vote: b
Vote: c

OUTPUT:

b
```

I have used debug50 to see where the problem lies, but I could not get to the solution. Has anyone also done pset3 and has any helpful ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the input you provide together with the output and the expected output. "it seems not to work." is not a very useful description.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= candidate_count; i++)` Index should start at 0 as in all the other loops.

Comment: Thanks Gerhardh, especially for the quick answer. There is no error message. It just does not output what I like to see. It outputs (e.g. if I input alice bob and 5 votes) the following:

Comment: `````./plurality alice bob
Number of voters: 5
Vote: alice
Vote: alice
Vote: alice
Vote: bob
Vote: bob
0
alice
3
bob
0

Comment: I would like the following printed: the name of the highest voter, all the names of the candidates and all the votes of the candidates. I have change the loop remark you've mentioned - the output did not change

Comment: Please edit your question to include input and output

Comment: Any vote that does not match a candidate should cause some message "invalid vote". Do you get these? And again: Please edit the question to include input and output. Comments are not the right place for that.

Comment: Please be aware that changing the code in the question after comments or answers have been given, is basically a no-go. It makes all responses useless and the time spent is wasted! You should never ever do this. If there are new versions that are relevant, just add them to the question. But don't remove the initial code.

Comment: If one or more answers helped you solve your problem you should think about accepting one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your vote function seems to be fine. Print_winner, not so much. Some redundancy, some weird stuff. Try to keep it simple. I see you already solved it, but might help to compare where you used stuff/lines you didn't need.

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int winner = 0;
    // The var 'winner' is an int, a number of votes, not a name.

    // Finding the highest number of votes
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
    if (candidates[i].votes > winner)
        {
            winner = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    // Printing the names of all candidates with 'winner' number of votes
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (candidates[j].votes == winner)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[j].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martinez. Makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    // LOOK OUT HERE FOR THE MISTAKE
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++ ;
            return true;
        }
        return false;  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR!
    }
}
```

If you don't find a match during first iteration, you return from the function and `bob` never gets a change to count some votes.
You need to move the second `return` after the loop.

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And another problem:

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > highest_vote)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = highest_vote;
        }
    }
```

First of all: The index should start at 0 as mentioned in my comment.
Second:
You must update `highest_vote`, not the other way around.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > highest_vote)
        {
            highest_vote = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed it, but I get the same output.

Comment: I suspect the print_winner function to be the reason this output

Comment: Updated it as you suggested:

Comment: Ah! I found it - as you said, I must update highest_vote. Thanks! I oversaw that one completely